# How to get all tweets of given username ( in PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I already got 3200 tweets using API v1.1 but I need all the tweets so I also used cron job as background process but it didn't increase the tweets .

Please suggest me if any way possible either scraping or using API.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: "didn't work" means what exactly? What went wrong? Maybe your code is fixable, but we can't fix what we can't see. If you'd like some help, please give us some details we can work with. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't work means after 3200 tweets further access is not allowed anymore via API on tweets.

Comment: Check what time that limit expires. Make sure your job does not run again until the counter is reset. Or set it to access a smaller number more frequently.

Answer (score -1):

The best way getting Tweets is API. For me, I'm using [twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth). I don't understand how to get all tweet of users. Twitter does not let to get tweet more than 200. So you can get 200 tweets per query for one user.

You can create a listener or cronjob for getting last tweets. If you create a listener, when any user send tweets you get simply.